# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/model/SelectItem

Tags: jetty, opennms

I am getting the following exception trace when I run a web app deployed into Jety web server. It looks I am missing some jar file. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /PMCounters/default.jsp. Reason:

```
javax/faces/model/SelectItem
```

Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/model/SelectItem
    at com.ericsson.dae.pm.dao.VirtualConfigTableDAO.(VirtualDaeConfigTableDAO.java:41)
    at org.apache.jsp.default_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.default_jsp:162)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:109)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:389)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:940)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:874)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

HERE IS my WEB.XML:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
      <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: is your .jsp properly mapped ?

Comment: did you put jsf jar files in the lib directory?

Comment: yes all jsf jar files are in place which are:

    com-sun-commons-beanutils.jar
    com-sun-commons-collections.jar
    com-sun-commons-digester.jar
    jsf-api.jar
    jsf-impl.jar

Comment: I have added my web.xml above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically that error is when there are multiple versions of that class available, make sure you don't have multiple version of jars with that class in your application, or that the application server isn't giving you one version and your webapp is packaging another version.

Comment: I have below listed jar files under both WEB-INF/lib directory of the application and /opt/opennms/jetty-webapps/lib/ext/jsf. I removed those under WEB-INF/lib but it still does not work. Is there st else you can suggest? Thanks.

    com-sun-commons-beanutils.jar,
    com-sun-commons-collections.jar,
    com-sun-commons-digester.jar,
    jsf-api.jar,
    jsf-impl.jar.

Comment: perhaps your unpacking a war file and getting those files back each time?

Comment: I have made sure I dont have those jar files again and again but still have the problem. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I removed all those jar files from everywhere. Still have the problem.

Comment: I have the following in the jetty.log:


2012-05-22 14:23:04,994 WARN  [qtp522201969-376] ServletHandler: /PMCounters/default.jsp
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/model/SelectItem
 at com.ericsson.dae.pm.dao.VirtualDaeConfigTableDAO.<init>(VirtualDaeConfigTableDAO.java:41)
 at org.apache.jsp.default_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.default_jsp:162)

Comment: if your getting that same error then you still have multiple versions of that class available to the classloader in question, next step would be to crack open your jars one by one and look for an implementation hitching a ride.  you can use search.maven.org to find jars that have that class in them: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22%20javax.faces.model.SelectItem%20%22

Comment: I searched for the entire file system of jetty web server to find a single instance of those files. None of them is present anywhere.

Comment: you misunderstand, there are a number of other jar files that might have those classes in them, myfaces-api.jar for example bundles those classes as well I believe.  you are getting another copy from somewhere, just have to find it :)

Comment: I removed the use of so mentioned bloody class from my implementation and it works now.